# How do I add a logo in the center of the header?

Tags: html, css

I recently purchased this theme and the author has stopped responding. And I really need to set it up but I am new to coding and stuff.

Here is the link to the website: [Click here](http://gizmofreak.in/123/)

I want to add a logo on the top center of the page and make sure it stays there when moving to other pages without affecting the responsiveness of the website.

Comment: Any idea if you're going to use an <img> or set it as a <div> with a background? If you're using a straight <img> just set it to display: block; and add a margin: 0 auto; , that will keep it centered.

Comment: As long as I get the final result as what I want, I really don't care. Because I am unaware about the differences.

Comment: I hear you. Try running with a straight image and go from there. I put a link to an example in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your logo you could use a `<img>`. Set it to `display: block` and add `margin: 0 auto;`. http://codepen.io/evanrbriggs/pen/gwlIq this could be taken a step further to be responsive by adding `width: 100%;` and then set your `max-width: ;` to your desired maximum width, or the actual width of the logo used. Incase it's larger then smaller device displays.

Alternatively, you could create a `div` with a `background` ( `background: url();, background-size, etc` ) , with a set `width` and `height` and add `margin: 0 auto;` and do the above stuff.

Comment: No problem! Goodluck.